# Node.js WebSocket Server: How to handle individual subscriptions from clients

Tags: node.js, express, apache-kafka, ws, kafkajs

I want to build a WebSocket server (node.js, express, ws) that can handle individual subscriptions for each client.

The ideas is that the client (socket.io) sends a message with a subscription request to the server and the server then sends back the corresponding data stream from a kafka consumer (kafkajs) to the client.

The basic data pipeline is already working:
kafka broker -> consumer -> WebSocket client

Unfortunately the server is currently sending all data from all consumers to all ws-clients.

How can I manage multiple clients with individual data subscriptions?

Below I have included a simplified representation of my current ws-server.

```js
async function create_consumer(topic) {
    const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: topic });
    await consumer.connect();
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic: topic, fromBeginning: false });
    return consumer;
};

async function send_consumer_to_client(ws, consumer) {
    await consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
            wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
                if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    client.send(JSON.stringify({
                        "value": message,
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
    });
}

const main = async () => {
    consumer_1 = await create_consumer("topic_1");
    consumer_2 = await create_consumer("topic_2");

    server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Lisening on port ${server.address().port}`));

    wss.on("connection", async function connection(ws) {
        console.log("A client has connected!");

        ws.on("message", async function message(message) {
            await send_consumer_to_client(ws, consumer_1);
        });

        ws.on("close", function close() {
            console.log("A client has disconnected");
        });
    });
};

main().catch(console.error);
```

**UPDATE 1**

I have figured out a solution to handle individual subscriptions for multiple clients by using:

- a Map() of clients and topics
- a Map() of topics and consumers

Each time a client subscribes to a particular topic, the group of clients updates accordingly for the wss.clients.forEach send-event.

I have no idea if this is a scalable solution for many clients and topics, but at least it's working. Does anyone know if this is a legit and scalable approach?

```js
async function run_consumer(consumer) {
    await consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
            await send_to_clients(clients, topic, message);
        }
    });
};

async function send_to_clients(clients, topic, message) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        const client_topic = clients.get(client).topic;
        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN, client_topic == topic) {
            client.send(message);
        }
    });
};

let clients = new Map();
let consumers = new Map();

const main = async () => {
    server.listen(PORT, HOST, () => console.log(`Lisening on port : ${server.address().port} of address: ${server.address().address}`))

    const consumer_groups = {
        'gid_1': 'topic_1',
        'gid_2': 'topic_2',
    };

    Object.entries(consumer_groups).forEach(async ([groupId, topic]) => {
        const consumer = await create_consumer(groupId, topic);
        consumers.set(topic, consumer);
        await run_consumer(consumer);
    });

    wss.on('connection', async function connection(ws) {
        const id = uuidv4();
        const metadata = { 'id': id };
        clients.set(ws, metadata);

        ws.on('message', async function message(msg) {
            const data = JSON.parse(msg);
            const metadata = clients.get(ws);

            if (data.op == 'subscribe') {
                const topic = data.topic;
                metadata['topic'] = topic;
                clients.set(ws, metadata)
            };
        });

        ws.on('close', function close() {
            clients.delete(ws)
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: The topic and the groupId should not be the same. Also, if you read the kafkaJS docs, calling subscribe more than once will read from all of those topics into one consumer instance, so "consumer_2" here is probably not getting separate data from "consumer_1"

Comment: Overall, you need the client to provide some ID that they should subscribe to in order to filter messages effectively, rather than just a single address/port.

Comment: Yes, groupId=topic is not good, I've changed it now. But if 2 consumers have different groupIds then the consumers should be separated, shouldn't they? Only if the 2 consumers have the same groupId then multiple subs will be attached to the same consumer as far as i understand.

Comment: Different groups will be separate, yes. Isn't that what you wanted? Different websocket client subscribe to different topics?

Comment: Yes indeed, i was just confused about your point about one consumer reading from multiple topics. I had different groupIds already before (groupId=topic) so I expected that these 2 consumers were really separated. Maybe I misunderstood you...

Comment: I guess my problem is not even the consumers, but rather the wss, because the wss is sending the 2 consumers to all clients (wss.clients.forEach...). I'm currently trying to handle the wss with a Map() of clients and consumers...Not sure if this is the right way to go though...

Comment: Right. I think you need multiple websocket servers (perhaps behind a reverse proxy) that is like `server:port/topic1` vs `server:port/topic2`, which controls what topic is actually being read from... Or you could use the Kafka REST Proxy instead with its Streaming HTTP consumer support.

Comment: I need to think about that...With this setup each client could only receive data from 1 topic, right? I guess I would like to keep the flexibility, that a client could also read from multiple topics...But as said, I need to think about it, I'm not very familiar with web development and and even less with websockets... Thanks for your support, I need to come back, when I have digested a bit more...

Comment: Take a look at the [Kafka REST Proxy docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/rest-proxy.html#consume-records)... In particular, you HTTP POST a consumerGroup object with a list of topics. This maintains an internal database mapping of groups to topics. Then you can consume out of the route for that groupId using HTTP requests. I feel like you need to do something very similar here.